# $a_n= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \sin(nt) \mathrm dt \implies \sum n^2|a_n|^2$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

If $a_n= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(t) \sin(nt) \mathrm dt $ then how to show $\sum n^2|a_n|^2$ is convergent ?

I've only noticed that sum is same as $\sum |\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f'(t) \cos(nt) \mathrm dt|^2$ but what to do now ?

Comment: The result is false unless there are hypotheses on $f$ you haven't told us about.

Comment: Oh yes, $f \in C^1[-\pi,+\pi]$

Comment: Looks like you didn't integrate by parts correctly.

Comment: It looks correct to me :(

Comment: So you think $\int \sin (nt)\ dt = -\cos (nt)$?

Comment: I did as $na_n=\int f(t) n \sin(nt) \mathrm dt= -[f(t) \cos (nt) \mathrm dt]_{-\pi \to \pi} -.....$ .. what's wrong with this ?

Comment: OK, I see what you're doing now. You're done! Just use the fact that the Fourier coefficients of any continuous function are square-summable

Comment: I already did it but probably using slightly different way, I used the fact that trigonometric polynomials are dense to show exist some $M$ such that $n|a_n| < \frac{M}{n}$ for all $n$. Can you please show how to do with fourier ? I'm not good in using fourier stuffs